# TroubleShooting Error 401 Unauthorised

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, credentials, ntlm

Have been tasked to connect with a SharePoint site hosted by another company...when asked about theitr authorisation this is the response I got..

> The authentication is annoying to work with in code.  I think you need to set up a credential cache in code, as well as setting some headers in the request.  You might also have to manage the initial 401, and subsequent redirect to authenticate as NTLM is a multi-step authentication

I'm assuming they are referring to the Infamous Double Hop Sharepoint issue...I'm using the below code to connect but am being Refused (Error 401 Unauthorised).

I really have no further ideas...anyone?

```
            try
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            Uri uri = new Uri(FbaTxt.Text);

            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(uri);

            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(USER, PWD, DOMAIN);
            CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
            cc.Add(uri, "NTLM", nc);
            ctx.Credentials = cc;

            //get the web
            Web w = ctx.Web;

            //LOAD LISTS WITH ALL PROPERTIES
            var lists = ctx.LoadQuery(w.Lists);

            //execute the query
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            FbaLst.Items.Clear();
            foreach (List theList in lists)
            {
                FbaLst.Items.Add(theList);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is a double-hop issue since you're passing explicit credentials.
However, I don't understand this piece of code:

```
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(USER, PWD, DOMAIN);
        CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
        cc.Add(uri, "NTLM", nc);
        ctx.Credentials = cc;
```

Should simply be IMO:

```
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(USER, PWD, DOMAIN);
        m_ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
        ctx.Credentials = nc;
```

Comment: The above change to the code worked...thx...!!